# how to navigate through complex JSON dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to navigate through a complex nested JSON, however my attempt didn't get me too far as it keeps returning me the last `index` JSON.

This is how my Objects looks like, and trying to navigate through it and getting other objs/schemas that are in `$ref`.

[image]

Raw JSON

```
 {
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
      "Id": {
         "format": "int32",
         "type": "integer"
      },
      "Status": {
         "enum": [
            "Preparing",
            "AwaitingCompletion",
            "Cancelled",
            "Completed"
         ],
         "type": "string"
      },
      "ExternalReference": {
         "type": "string"
      },
      "Customer": {
         "$ref": "#/definitions/Customer"
      },
      "OrderLineGroups": {
         "type": "array",
         "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/OrderLineGroup"
         }
      },
      "Promotions": {
         "type": "array",
         "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/PromotionSummary"
         }
      },
      "OriginatingSite": {
         "type": "object",
         "properties": {
            "Id": {
               "format": "int32",
               "type": "integer"
            },
            "PropertyCode": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "StoreCode": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      },
      "CustomData": {
         "type": "object",
         "additionalProperties": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
               "type": "object"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In my code I have done `for()` and `hasOwnProperty()`, however my problem is that it doesn't give me all the JSON back even the condition is met (e.g if there's no type property), it only gives the last `index` or object that doesn't have `type` property. Also doesn't return me any of the objects if `type` property is `array`.

```js
// Get property of #/definitions/obj
let prop =  apiDefinition[splitResponse.split('/')[2]].properties;
console.log([prop])
var s = [apiDefinition[splitResponse.split('/')[2]].properties];

// Transform JS Object of #/definitions/Obj to JSON 
var parentJSON = JSON.stringify(apiDefinition[splitResponse.split('/')[2]]);

for (var x in prop) {
  if (prop.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
    if (prop[x].type && prop[x].type === 'array') {
      console.log('All type Array >> ', x);
      let objKeyProp = apiDefinition[prop[x].items.$ref.split('/')[2]];
      let objJsonStringified = JSON.stringify(objKeyProp);
      let refString = '{"$ref"'+':' + '"' + prop[x].items.$ref + '"}';
      this.compiledJson = JSON.parse(parentJSON.replace(refString, objJsonStringified)); 
    } else if (!prop[x].type) {
      console.log('all arrays >> ', x)
      let objKeyProp = apiDefinition[prop[x].$ref.split('/')[2]];
      let objJsonStringified = JSON.stringify(objKeyProp);
      let refString = '{"$ref"'+':' + '"' + prop[x].$ref + '"}';
      this.compiledJson = JSON.parse(parentJSON.replace(refString, objJsonStringified));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow... Why are you stringifying and parsing JSON in a loop? Just parse it to an object and perform whatever manipulations you need to do on the object.

Comment: Also, you'll want to explain what exactly you're trying to do; it's definitely not clear from the code.